# Power Query: Replace Value based on other column

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have a dataset of Degree Programs and Colleges that I am working with, but several colleges have had name changes in recent years.

```
+------+------------------------------+------------------+
| Year |           College            |     Program      |
+------+------------------------------+------------------+
| 2018 | College of Arts & Humanities | BA Communication |
| 2017 | College of Arts & Humanities | BA Communication |
| 2016 | College of Arts & Sciences   | BA Communication |
+------+------------------------------+------------------+
```

What I want to do is replace the college name on each reference of the program with the college name from the latest year. In my example above, it would only change 2016 to "College of Arts & Humanities."

I'm still very new to power query and the like, so I haven't the slightest on how to handle this...

I can create a new column with the information, or replace text on the column, I just need a way that isn't manual.

Has anyone else ran into this? Or have an idea on how to approach it? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. :)

---

**Update:** Replace values won't work, as some colleges were split and there's not a simple A-B transition.

When I say "several" colleges, 1 college split into two, and 2 others were renamed. We're talking about several thousand records in one dataset, all different colleges. I don't have any sort of a reference table for the name changes. I've been working on this dataset for 2 days, and the easiest logic I can find to make this work is to replace the college name on each program with the college name from the latest year.

---

**Final Update:** Thanks to @user9264230. After updating the references in the provided code, it looks like that took care of the issue!

Comment: Have you tried using the "Replace Values" button on the Home tab of the query editor (Transform section)?

Comment: You say 'several colleges' - is your example a case of ONE college, which has changed name? Are your 'several' colleges in the same table? If so, how do you determine which 'old' and 'new' college names are related?

Comment: @Olly the latest records have the latest college name. There's unfortunately no relation in the old and new college names other than the tribal knowledge.

Comment: @AlexisOlson I can't use Replace values unfortunately. For example, The college of Arts and sciences was split into two colleges: Arts & Humanities and Science & Engineering. The latest college name on the program is the easiest way I can find to make the replacement.

Comment: With no relation, how can you possibly automate a link?

Comment: @Olly, The program name/Code matches across all 3 years. When I said no relation, I meant we don't have a reference table that says "This program was in this college, now it's over here"

Comment: So in your example, "BA Communication" is the key that links the three rows? This value doesn't apply to any other college?

Comment: correct, @Olly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a key field that distinguishes one college from another. If it is field Program then use code

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Program"}, {{"Year", each List.Max([Year]), type number}}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Grouped Rows",{"Program", "Year"},Source,{"Program", "Year"},"Source",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
List = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Source", {"College"}, {"College"}),
#"Merged Queries1" = Table.NestedJoin(Source,{"Program"},List,{"Program"},"List",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries1", "List", {"College"}, {"College.1"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Table2",{"College"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

Otherwise replace all instances of Program with name of desired field such as Key

Comment: Thank you @user9264230 ! I think that did the trick, I'm working on validating it now.